# Installing devtools in R on a cluster. unable to load shared object openssl

Tags: r, linux, cluster-computing

I have been pulling my hair out for days trying to get the `devtools R package` installed on a cluster as a local user.

All other R packages are installed locally. many other linux packages are installed locally.

Please let me know what more I can provide to you so someone can assist me with solving this issue.

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘git2r’ in dyn.load(file,
>   DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):  unable to load shared object
>   '/home/CAM/anesta/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/git2r/libs/git2r.so':
>   libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

Edit:

```
-bash-4.2$ ldd /home/CAM/anesta/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/git2r/lib‌​s/g2r.so
ldd: /home/CAM/anesta/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/git2r/lib‌​s/git2r.so: No such file or directory
```

unfortunately, after R fails to load git2r, it deletes the local install directory.

More info:
I locally installed openssl which is where libcrypto.so.1.1 is located.

```
-bash-4.2$ ldd /home/CAM/anesta/tools/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.1 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc9cf57000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => not found
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5bef8af000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5bef693000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5bef2d2000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5befd2d000)
```

I am beginning to think there is an issue where the R is looking at both the local openssl install and the server openssl install which are probably two different versions.

```
#!/bin/bash

#if [[ `hostname -s` =~ -submit- ]]; then
#export PATH=/tgcapps/environment_modules/modules-3.2.10/Modules/3.2.10/bin/:$PATH
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tgcapps/tcl/tcl8.5.12/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
#source /tgcapps/environment_modules/modules-3.2.10/Modules/3.2.10/init/bash
#fi

#CURL
export PATH=/home/CAM/anesta/tools/curl7/lib/pkgconfig$PATH
export PATH=/home/CAM/anesta/tools/curl7/lib/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc$PATH
export PATH=/home/CAM/anesta/tools/curl7$PATH
export PATH=/home/CAM/anesta/tools/openssl$PATH
export PATH=/home/CAM/anesta/tools/openssl/lib/pkgconfig/openssl.pc$PATH
export PATH=/home/CAM/anesta/tools/openssl/lib/pkgconfig$PATH
export PATH=/home/CAM/anesta/tools/bzip2/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/home/CAM/anesta/tools/perl:$PATH
export PERL5LIB=/home/CAM/anesta/tools/perl/lib:$PATH


#R
export LIBRARY_PATH="/home/CAM/anesta/tools/curl7/:/home/CAM/anesta/tools/openssl/:home/CAM/anesta/tools/perl/:$LIBRARY_PATH"

export R_LIBS=home/CAM/anesta/local/R_libs:/home/CAM/anesta/tools/openssl/lib/pkgconfig
export R_LIBS=/home/CAM/anesta/tools/openssl/lib/pkgconfig/openssl.pc

export R_LIBS=/home/CAM/anesta/tools/curl7/lib/pkgconfig
export R_LIBS=/home/CAM/anesta/tools/curl7/lib/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc

#export MODULEPATH="$MODULEPATH:/isg/shared/modulefiles"

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/CAM/anesta/toos/perl/lib/5.26.0:/home/CAM/anesta/tools/openssl/lib/pkgconfig:/home/CAM/anesta/tools/openssl/lib/pkgconfig/openssl.pc:/home/CAM/anesta/tools/curl7/lib/pkgconfig:/home/CAM/anesta/tools/curl7/lib/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc
module load R/3.4.1


if [[ `hostname -s` =~ [Tt][Gg][Cc] ]]; then
module add libstdc++/6.0.13
module load gcc torque
fi

export ALLOW_WGCNA_THREADS=30
export png_REQUIRES="libpng"
```

Second Edit:

```
-bash-4.2$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/CAM/anesta/tools/openssl/lib:$LD_LIBRA‌​RY_PATHdd /home/CAM/anesta/tools/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.1
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe361a5000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /home/CAM/anesta/tools/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f1eaf242000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1eaf033000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1eaee17000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1eaea56000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1eaf936000)
```

Comment: What is the output of `ldd /home/CAM/anesta/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/git2r/libs/git2r.so`?

Comment: just updated post. hope it is helpful.

Comment: Ok. What is the output of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/CAM/anesta/tools/openssl/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ldd /home/CAM/anesta/tools/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.1`? If all libraries are found, you should set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the environment and try again.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you Ralf!